# Is there a way to have CUDA 9 and 10 installed at the same environment to run Tensorflow 2.0 and early versions together?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have models written in tensorflow's early versions, compatible with CUDA 9 version. I want to switch hereafter to tensorflow 2.0 but have to convert CUDA version into 10. But if I do that, I will not be able to run my early written codes with new CUDA version. How to avoid this version conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many versions of CUDA installed as you want. Just make sure that the correct version is specified in the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You can check your variables with `echo $PATH` and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple versions of CUDA on your system, but in this case, I would not recommend it. There is a Tensorflow 2.0 tool that converts your code (if written correctly) to Tensorflow 2.0. You can read more about this [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade). This will enable you to run all your code in CUDA 10.

For single files use:

```
tf_upgrade_v2 — infile foo.py — outfile foo-upgraded.py
```

To update a full project use:

```
tf_upgrade_v2 --intree my_project/ --outtree my_project_v2/ --reportfile report.txt
```

Note: You might need to install this script first.

EDIT: If you still have older TensorFlow functions you want to use. You can use `tf.compat.v1` as described in the [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).

Comment: It's totally okay to have multiple versions of CUDA on the system. There's nothing wrong with it. I've had multiple versions without any issues. The only thing you have to worry about is making sure only one CUDA version exists in the PATH and other environmental variables.

Comment: I also think your solution wouldn't allow to run models created with previous TensorFlow versions.

Comment: @thushv89 I agree that it's possible to run multiple versions of CUDA on one system I just wouldn't recommend it. Old models can indeed cause problems. Very well noted. If you still want to use models that are not made for tf 2.0 you could use `tf.compat.v1` to use those functions. This seems like a much cleaner solution to me.

Comment: Can you give an example where things can go wrong? Ultimately it's just a software. If the isolation is correctly done (docker / virtual env / VM) I don't see anything not to recommend.

Comment: You are right, as far as I can see it won't give any direct problems. However, it might in the future. I would not advise it because it is good to update dependencies as soon as possible.